# Unable to use exported function from WebAssembly module?

Tags: webassembly

The following JavaScript code is throwing the error `myMathModule.exports is undefined`:

```
<script>
fetch("test.wasm")
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.arrayBuffer();
    })
    .then(function(buffer) {
        var moduleBufferView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        var myMathModule = WebAssembly.instantiate(moduleBufferView);


        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            console.log(myMathModule.exports.doubleExp(i));
        }
    });
</script>
```

`test.wasm` exports the `doubleExp` function.

Answer (score 1):

[`WebAssembly.instantiate`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#webassemblyinstantiate) is a promise. You're trying to use the `WebAssembly.Instance` that the promise returns when it completes. Something like

```
fetch("test.wasm")
.then(function(response) {
    return response.arrayBuffer();
})
.then(function(buffer) {
    var moduleBufferView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    WebAssembly.instantiate(moduleBufferView)
    .then(function(instantiated) {
        const instance = instantiated.instance;
        console.log(instance.exports.doubleExp(i));
    })
});
```